# CRM 2013 Business Rule export option?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, business-rules

Is it possible to export/import business rules written in CRM 2013?
I am doing crm migration and adding some new validation rules using business rules feature , instead of javascript.But not getting any support to export these business rules and reimport them before migration the latest database of CRM.

Does any one have better idea to do it ,other than javascript solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using **solutions**

Add that entity in the solutions and export that solutions and import it in the new environment